# Virtual Classes in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt, header-files

I'm having a problem with Eclipse's indexing. Here's a minimal working example.

I create a header file, Parent.h, in which I define the following virtual class:

```
class Parent
{
protected:
    virtual ~Parent() {}
public:
    virtual void OverrideMe() = 0;
};
```

Then, I create another header file, Child.h:

```
#include "Parent.h"

class Child : public Parent
{

};
```

Immediately, Eclipse complains that "Symbol Parent could not be resolved."

The problem magically goes away if I create a source file Parent.cpp and in it put #include "Parent.h". More strangely, it does not reappear if I delete this source file.

There seems to be something crazy going on with Eclipse's indexing? People with similar problems have recommended doing an "Index -> Rebuild". This does not work for me.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I _think_ it only indexes based on actual source files (that way, you don't get "false postives" from a bunch of similar classes which you may not be using). After all, indexing a header file that isn't being used makes no sense - you probably want to include it SOMEWHERE before it becomes useful to you.

Comment: Deleting the source file without forcing eclipse to rebuild its index will probably keep the index entries for `Parent`, hence the error does not reappear.